# How can I infer the index of a row of a table from event?

Tags: javascript

I have a button in each row in a table and a handler for onclick on a button:

```
<button onclick="handler1(event)">aa</button>
```

How can I determine the index of a row from the **event**?

**Note that** the signature of "handler1" can't be changed, namely only a single argument "event" can be passed to it.

```
function handler1(myEvent) {
   // index of a row from myEvent???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the handler is on some nested element, then traverse up the `event.currentTArget` using `.parentNode` until the `TR` is found.

```js
function handler1(myEvent) {
  var el = myEvent.currentTarget;
  while (el && el.nodeName !== "TR") {
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  console.log(el && el.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="handler1(event)">CLICK ME</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="handler1(event)">CLICK ME</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="handler1(event)">CLICK ME</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Bingi: Your question doesn't say that the handler is on a `td`. If it is, then add `.parentNode`.

Comment: parentNode will return td which has no "rowIndex"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the button inside `<td>` like:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><button onclick="handler1(event)">click</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><button onclick="handler1(event)">click</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

the following should work:

```
function handler1(event) {
  var rowIndex = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  console.log(rowIndex);
}
```